# Laravel query works when given values but not variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

OK, this is driving me insane.  Can someone please explain why

```php
Result::query()
    ->where('audit_id', $audit->id)
    ->where('result_type', 'App\Models\Touchpoint')
    ->whereIn('result_id', $tps)
    ->with('result')
    ->join('locations', function ($join) {
        $join->where('locations.id', $location->id);
    })
    ->join('location_weight', function ($join) {
        $join->on('results.result_id', '=', 'location_weight.weight_id')
            ->on('results.result_type', '=', 'location_weight.weight_type')
            ->on('locations.id', '=', 'location_weight.location_id');
    })
    ->get()
```

doesn't return results when $audit->id = 1 and $location->id = 1, yet

```php
Result::query()
    ->where('audit_id', 1)
    ->where('result_type', 'App\Models\Touchpoint')
    ->whereIn('result_id', $tps)
    ->with('result')
    ->join('locations', function ($join) {
        $join->where('locations.id', 1);
    })
    ->join('location_weight', function ($join) {
        $join->on('results.result_id', '=', 'location_weight.weight_id')
            ->on('results.result_type', '=', 'location_weight.weight_type')
            ->on('locations.id', '=', 'location_weight.location_id');
    })
    ->get()
```

does return the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first codeblock should throw an error. You're referencing a variable from the parent scope (`$location`) without passing it to the `use` language construct

```php
// This
->join('locations', function ($join) {
    $join->where('locations.id', $location->id);
})
```

```php
// should be
->join('locations', function ($join) use ($location) {
    $join->where('locations.id', $location->id);
})
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php  (See Example #3)